# Как сделать у неактивной кнопки изображение тусклым

Tags: wpf

Есть кнопка с изображением на ToolBar, команда отключена, кнопка не работает, а вот изображение не меняется. Нужен просто стандартный эффект неактивности. Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: А как вы вставляете изображение? Может быть вам поможет стиль или триггер.

Comment: Сделал через события, я думал что такое может автоматом должно происходить если isEnable=false.

Comment: А код? :-) Кстати, откуда, по-вашему, возьмётся изменённое изображение? Его WPF за вас создаст?

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, наверно, будет переписать темплейт для кнопки, где в триггере, реагирующем на активность кнопки, изменять прозрачность контента.